# Run a command line using PHP

Tags: php, cmd, exec

I am trying to run a command in CMD using PHP and get a output in web. After doing some research I came to know about `exec('command', $output, $return_var)` function. And i got the output when i am running `ping www.google.com` because after  the execution is complete the command is getting end. But what I am looking for when I run the command I need to get the output `Node Ready` and as the execution is not getting ended and its running that's why server its waiting for the output. Is there anyway where i can get the output in this condition.

My CMD output is :
[image: CMD OUTPUT]

This function its helping me to run the CMD and execute the command. How will I get the output in the web??

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows") { 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}
```

Thank you

Comment: For suppose I am running the command `cd C:\Users\Piyush\Desktop\multichain-windows-1.0.4 && multichaind chain2 -daemon` when i run in cmd i will get my final output `Node Ready` and it will not end it. So i need that output in web. I have added image

Comment: Please check the image. I want when I get the Node ready. It will run in background displaying message and I can start using my same application

Comment: Running background services is not very suitable for PHP, but if you really want to have that you may want to create helper script as in https://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window redirect its output to a file, run from PHP and start checking output file in sleeping loop until you see `Node ready`. This is really ugly, but it can work.

Comment: I am able to run the command in background but how can I get the output of it. Please check my edit. I have added one function